# Blank page running python script

Tags: python, html

I have a HTML-page from which I pass some input values to a python script to be processed there. What I want to do is to show the results of the calculations. Just on a white page. No formatting or anything. Just plain numbers.

The problem is that I am getting just a blank page and I can't figure out why.

I did a lot of research but none of the solutions provided applied direclty to my issue.

It seems that the values are being passed on and processed since i don't get an error message nor there is an error in the error log nor any indications in the web console.

I am running a LAMP webserver which apache2 on it. The apache2 is correctly configured for running python and cgi.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Eval Main</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function()
         {
             $('#ok').click(function()
             {
                 $.ajax(
                 {
                     url: "/cgi-bin/verlauf_Grenzen.py",
                     data:
                     {
                         a_test: $("#testa").val(),
                         v_test: $("#testv").val(),
                         s_test: $("#tests").val(),
                         j_test: $("#testj").val()
                     },
                     success: function(response)
                     {
                         handleResponse(response);
                     }
                 });
             });
         });
      </script>
      <form action="/cgi-bin/verlauf_Grenzen.py" method="POST">
         <input id="testa" type="number" name="a" />
         <input id="testv" type="number" name="v" />
         <input id="tests" type="number" name="s" />
         <input id="testj" type="number" name="j" />
         <button id="ok" type="submit" value="Submit">Click</button>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

verlauf_Grenzen.py

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/python3.6

    import json, time, glob, os
    import numpy as np
    from ruck import Cases
    import cgi, cgitb

    cgitb.enable()

    print("Content-type:text/html\n")

    def index(req):
        form = cgi.FieldStorage()

        a = form.getvalue('a_test')
        v = form.getvalue('v_test')
        s = form.getvalue('s_test')
        j = form.getvalue('j_test')

        cases = Cases(a,v,s,j)

        #does something here

        return x #x ist a single number

        print("<html>")
        print("<head>")
        print("<title>CALC</title>")
        print("</head>")
        print("<body>")
        print("<h2>Your name is {} </h2>".format(x))
        print("</body>")
        print("</html>")
        req.write(x)
```

ruck.py

```
        #!/usr/local/bin/python3.6

        import cgi, cgitb

        cgitb.enable()

        class Cases(object):

            def __init__(self, a, v, s, j):
                self.a = a
                self.v = v
                self.s = s
                self.j = j

           # does something here (a few functions/methods)

                return x, tj, ta, tv, tg, self.v, self.a

            def __call__(self):
                self.case_one()
                self.case_two()
                self.case_three()
                self.case_four()
```

Both scripts work fine and cause no errors.
Thanks for any help in advance. I am pretty new in web programming.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here, both in the JS and the Python.

Firstly, on the JS side, your event handler doesn't prevent the default submission of the form - you should use `event.preventDefault()`. Secondly, you don't seem to have defined the `handleResponse()` function that you call within the Ajax success method.

On the Python side, your `verlauf_Grenzen` file defines an `index` function but does not seem to ever call it. Inside that function, there is a `return x` statement halfway down which returns unconditionally, so none of the subsequent code that prints the response will ever be executed.

Finally, if you are doing anything more than trivial work, you should really consider a proper Python micro-framework such as Flask rather than using CGI.

Comment: ok. I understand. I have just one question. Can I import the flask into my script or do I have to create a new script and calling the other script from there?

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it:

Python:

```
import json, time, glob, os
import numpy as np
from ruck import Cases
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

a = form.getvalue('a_test')
v = form.getvalue('v_test')
s = form.getvalue('s_test')
j = form.getvalue('j_test')

cases = Cases(a,v,s,j)

# does something here (a few functions/methods)

json.dumps(somedata)
```

ajax in my HTML:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#btn2').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'https://192.168.80.27/cgi-bin/verlauf_Grenzen.py',
      type: 'post',
      data: $.('.senddata').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        window.alert("Data sent!");
         },
     });
   });
});
</script>
<input id="btn2" class="button" type="button" value="Send Values"  value="Click"/>

<script>       
$(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'https://192.168.80.27/cgi-bin/verlauf_Grenzen.py',
      type: 'json',
      data: {},
      success: function(data) {
            var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('#xbtn').html(jsondata);
        window.alert("Success!!!");
         },
     });
  });
});
</script>
<input id="btn" class="button" type="button" value="Load results" value="Click"/>
<span id="xbtn"></span>
```